# Disk quota in GeoServer tile caching

Tags: geoserver

In GeoServer, to speed up the imaging process, we use tile caching. Under tile caching menu, we can arrange disk quota. Also, under tile caching menu on the left if we select caching defaults, we can enable "in memory BlobStore" options". There is "Cache Hard Memory Limit(mb)" option there. That made me confused. Are they different? If so, what is the difference between them?

Moreover, I understand that tile caching is stored in file system if we do not enable "In memory BlobStore options" under caching defaults. If we enable that option, is RAM used to store caches instead of file systems?

[image]

[image]